# Unable to transfer str to bytes in python 3 messaging service

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out how to transfer `str` to `bytes` in Python 3.

This is the client code:

```
import socket
import threading

tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False

def receving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            while True:
                data, addr = socket.recvfrom(1024).decode()
                print (data)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 0

server = ('127.0.0.1',5000)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)

rT = threading.Thread(target=receving, args=("RecvThread",s))
rT.start()

alias = input("Name: ")
message = input(alias + "-> ")
while message != 'q':
    if message != '':
        s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": " + message.encode(), server.encode())
    tLock.acquire()
    message = input(alias + "-> ")
    tLock.release()
    time.sleep(0.2)

shudown = True
rT.join()
s.close()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/client fixing.py", line 35, in <module>
    s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": " + message.encode(), server.encode())
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `":"` is an `str` (string) object. You could just do `b':'`:

```
s.sendto(alias.encode() + b": " + message.encode(), server.encode())
```

but you might find it simpler if you used `str.format().encode()`

```
s.sendto("{}: {}".format(alias, message).encode(), server.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

`s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": " + message.encode(), server.encode())`

`": "`, which is a `string`, is being concatenated with two `bytestrings` (we know they're `bytestrings` because `.encode()` is called on them.  This is an error in Python3, but it can be fixed by calling `.encode()` on the string.

The second parameter to `Socket.sendto` should be an *address*.  The exact type of the address depends on the [socket's family](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families).  In this case you have correctly defined address as a tuple (`server = ('127.0.0.1',5000)`), but you are erroneously calling `.encode()` on it.

Try changing the line to:

`s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": ".encode() + message.encode(), server)`

and the error will be fixed.

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @ChristopherSeddon I've edited my answer - there was a comma after `message.encode()` that converted the combined first three elements to a tuple.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\client fixing.py", line 36, in <module>
    s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": ".encode() + message.encode() + server.encode())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'